# Expected value of probability of intersection.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

let's assume we choose at random two subsets $A$ and $B$ of a finite set $X$ (i.e. $|X|=n$). By randomness I mean that $Pr[x\in A] = \frac1{n}$ for each $x\in X$, the same for $B$. What will be the average size of their intersection? More formally, I would like to compute:

$$E[|A \cap B|\ |\ |A|, |B|]$$

I tried to write it as a sum of expected values with additional condition about the size of $A\cap B$, but it leads me to a result which is not necessarily less than $1$, so either I've made a mistake or my whole reasoning has been wrong. Is there any tricky computation of this expression?

Comment: What do you mean by $\Pr[A]$, $\Pr[B]$ and $\Pr[A\cap B]$? $A$, $B$ and $A\cap B$ are not events. (Similarly, I don't get what you refer to when writing "probability of their intersection.")

Comment: Ok, I see I didn't introduce any measure on $2^X$, so we might as well use $|A|$ and $|B|$. I will edit the question.

Comment: I also assume $A,B$ are chosen independently? And what about the randomness -- each $x$ is added to $A$ independently with probability $1/n$, or is $A$ chosen uniformly at random among all subsets of size $1$ (or something else, even)? Note that both would satisfy $\Pr[x\in A]=1/n$ for all $x\in X$, yet they are quite different (and given the rest of the question, I suppose the former is the correct interpretation).

Comment: Yes, $A$ and $B$ are chosen independently and $A$ can be of any size, so we add each $x$ independently as you said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of elements $|A\cap B|$ in the interesection of $A,B$ given the values of $|A|$ and $|B|$, i.e. $|A\cap B \mid |A|, |B|$ is a random variable that takes values in $$\max\{0, |A|+|B|-|X|\},\ldots, \min\{|A|,|B|\}$$ 
Then $|A\cap B| \mid |A|, |B|$ follows the hypergeometric distribution (and not the binomial as in my initial effort) with parameters $|X|=n$ the population size, $|A|=a$ the number of successes in the population and $|B|=b$ the sample size.  The roles of $|A|$ and $|B|$ are interchangeable! Hence the expected value of $|A\cap B|\mid |A|,|B|$ is equal to $$E[|A\cap B|\mid |A|, |B|]=\frac{|A||B|}{|X|}=\frac{ab}{n}$$

---

Another way to see this, is that the probability that any given element of $X$ lies in $|A\cap B|$ given the values of $|A|,|B|$ is due to independece equal to $$P(x\in A\cap B)=P(x\in A)P(x\in B)=\frac{a}{n}\frac{b}{n}=\frac{ab}{n^2}$$ So \begin{align}E[|A\cap B|\mid |A|,|B|]&=E\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathsf 1_{\{x_i\in A\cap B\}}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}E\left[1_{\{x_i\in A\cap B\}}\right]\\&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}P(x_i\in A\cap B)=n\cdot \frac{ab}{n^2}=\frac{ab}{n}\end{align}

Comment: There is an issue here -- you use $n$ for two different things (it is originally defined as $\lvert X\rvert$).

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks for noticing! The second use was the usual notation for the binomial, and since it was not necessary, I deleted it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand or am convinced by the argument... even though you do get the probabilities $\frac{a}{n}$ and $\frac{b}{n}$, It seems strange that you get a binomial after this -- namely, I would have expected $n$ summands, but not independent (?)

Comment: @ClementC. Each $x$ has a probability of $ab/n^2$ to be in the set $Y$. This probability depends on the sizes $a,b$ and their relation to $n$. So I find this ok (not totally off the point at least). Then we go through $X$ and perform the same experiment on each of its elements separately, each having the same probability of success, where success stands for being in both $A, B$. I strongly believe that it is correct like this, but I am not totally affirmative.

Comment: The thing that puzzles with is that (i) I agree on $\Pr[x\in A\cap B] = \frac{ab}{n^2}$ for every $x\in X$; and (ii) surely, $\mathbb{E}[\lvert A\cap B\rvert\mid \lvert A\rvert, \lvert B\rvert] \leq \min(\lvert A\rvert,\lvert B\rvert)$. But the step arguing we can consider a binomial with parameter $\min(\lvert A\rvert,\lvert B\rvert)$ then confuses me, as we go from a probability holding for every $x\in X$ to a binomial with first parameter $<\lvert X\rvert$.

Comment: @ClementC. No problem with that. In binomial you can change first parameter to whatever you want once you have established $p$. But, if you want me to swear that this answer is correct, I cannot :)

Comment: I don't like it, for example if $|X| = 100$, $|A|=99$, $|B|=2$, then surely $|A\cap B| \ge 1$, but your $$E[Y] = 2\cdot \frac{2 \cdot 99}{100^2}  =0.0396$$ which is not greater nor equal to $1$.

Comment: @Jakubussimus Yeah, correct remark. $Y$ does not take values from $0$ to $\min\{a,b\}$. The upper bound is $\min\{a,b\}$ but the lower is not (necessarily) $0$ as your example shows.

Comment: @ClementC. So, by Jakubussimus example I saw that it is hypergeometric and not binomial.

Comment: @ClementC. Your idea with $n$ summands is correct, see my second effort, but I still find that they are independent. Am I still mistaken?

Comment: @Stef I can't see the problem, if there is one: the result does look correct to me...

Comment: @ClementC. Ok, thanks for insisting, I would not have seen the mistake.

Comment: My pleasure. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @JimmyR. Do you maybe have a good source explaining your answer and the theorems it uses?

Comment: another question, in the example by @Jakubussimus, shouldn't it be $$E[Y]=100\cdot \frac{2\cdot 99}{100^2}$$ since $n=100$? Then we get the result 1,98