# Probability of an Intersecton being non-empty

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Let U be a set s.t. $|U|=n$.
Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_{10}\subseteq U$ and $|X_i|=m_i$.
Given the cardinality of the $|X_i|$ and the cardinality of the pairwise intersections
$$|X_i \cap X_j| = l_{ij}, \text{ for } i\not=j,\forall i,j\in \{1,2,...,10\}
$$
What is the probability that $|X_1\cap X_2 \cap ... \cap X_{10}|>0$ ?
And how can I calculate it? 

It's quite some time ago that I learned about probability theory, and it wasn't my strongest subject. So I would be really grateful for any help.

All the best, Luca

---

Update:
I found this question that gave me some new ideas.
[Expected value of probability of intersection.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583470/expected-value-of-probability-of-intersection) 
I want to use the following formula
[image]
In my case, I change the equation to get
$$\big|\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^{10} X_i\big| = ...$$

The first two sums are given. Then I want to calculcate the expected value for each of the missing sums.
For the intersection of three sets I want to use:
$$E[|X_i\cap X_j|\mid |X_i|, |X_j|]=\frac{|X_i||X_j|}{|U|}=\frac{m_i m_j}{n}$$
but applied for three sets.
I thought about doing this:
Let's say I want to calculate the expected value for $|X_i\cap X_j \cap X_k|$. Therefore I calculate:
$$E[|X_i\cap X_j| \cap |X_i\cap X_k| | |X_i \cap X_j|, |X_i \cap X_k] = \frac{l_{ij}\cdot l_{ik}}{(l_{ij}+l_{ik})}$$

$$E[|X_i\cap X_j| \cap |X_j\cap X_k| | |X_i \cap X_j|, |X_j \cap X_k] = \frac{l_{ij}\cdot l_{jk}}{(l_{ij}+l_{jk})}$$

$$E[|X_i\cap X_k| \cap |X_j\cap X_k| | |X_i \cap X_k|, |X_j \cap X_k] = \frac{l_{ik}\cdot l_{jk}}{(l_{ik}+l_{jk})}$$
I divide by the $l_{ij}+l_{jk}$ since I know that
$$(X_i\cap X_j) \cap (X_j\cap X_k) \subseteq (X_i\cap X_j) \cup (X_j\cap X_k) \text{ and } |(X_i\cap X_j) \cup (X_j\cap X_k)|\leq l_{ij}+l_{jk}$$
And then I want to choose the middle of the three values as my expected value for the intersection of three sets.

Does that make any sense? I could then go on for 4 sets, then 5, ... until calculating my expected value for 10 sets.

Comment: What is random here? Over what random variables are you talking about the probability?

Comment: I am not sure what this means. But I think I am in the same situation like this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583470/expected-value-of-probability-of-intersection "By randomness I mean that $Pr[x\in A] = \frac1{n}$ for each $x\in X$, the same for $B$". In my case the $X_i$.

Comment: I understand your question to mean that $n$ and $m_i$ are fixed (with all the $m_i \leq n$).  We randomly pick 10 subsets of size $m_1, m_2, ..., m_{10}$. The question is then "what is the probability that (upon relabelling) the $_{10}C_2$ pairwise intersections have the necessary sizes, $l_{ij}$?"


To figure this one would count:  (i) the number of ways 10 subsets with the given sizes could be chosen and (ii) the number of these that meet the overlap conditions.  The probability would then be the second value divided by the first.

Can you confirm/deny this is what you are looking for?

Comment: @SelrachDunbar The $l_{ij}$ are also fixed. I have given 10 subsets of $U$. I know the cardinality of $U$, the 10 subsets, and the cardinality of their pairwise intersections. Each element of the $U$ has the same probability to be in one or more of the subsets. So the probability for an $x\in U$ to be in one of the $X_i$ is $\frac{m_i}{n}$ (i think?). Sorry, I'm probability theory is really not my subject..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we do not know the distribution of subsets $X_i$ chosen from $U$, then we cannot determine this probability.  For example, suppose we know that $U = \{a, b, c, d\}$ and sets $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are chosen such that $|X_i| = 2$ for all $i$, and $|X_i \cap X_j| = 1$ for all $i \not= j$.

Then we could have $X_1 = \{a, b\}, X_2 = \{a, c\}, X_3 = \{a, d\}$, and then

$$
X_1 \cap X_2 \cap X_3 = \{a\} \not= \emptyset
$$

Or, alternatively, we could have $X_1 = \{a, b\}, X_2 = \{b, c\}, X_3 = \{a, c\}$, and then

$$
X_1 \cap X_2 \cap X_3 = \emptyset
$$

To evaluate the probability that we have one of the collections equivalent to the former, as opposed to one that is equivalent to the latter, we need to know some kind of distribution for the $X_i$.  Without it, the probability cannot be determined.

---

If we know that all subsets of magnitude $k$ are *a priori* equally likely, then we can answer this question.  For instance, in the scenario above, the probability that the mutual intersection is non-empty is $1/2$: Wlog, the first subset is $\{a, b\}$ and the second subset is $\{a, c\}$, and then for the third subset, the only choices are $\{a, d\}$ and $\{b, c\}$, which are equally likely, but only one of which gives a non-empty mutual intersection.

But I think coming up with a closed-form answer for general $m_i$ and $I_{i, j}$ is likely to be challenging.  Let me think about that.

Comment: First, thank you @Brian for your answer. I am struggling to formally explain my case (as you might have noticed ;) ). A subset of, let's say size 2, can be, equally likely, any of the $\{a,b\}, \{a,c\} ,\{a,b\}$ and $\{b,c\}$. If $X_1=\{a,b\}$ then $X_2$ can still be $\{a,b\}$ with the same probability as  the other 3 possibilities.

Comment: @Luca: Even if that is the case, it is still prohibited in the conditional probability by the restrictions on the $I_{ij}$.

Answer (score 1):

I see.  Yes, if one were to select a point $x\in U$ at random, the probability of selecting a point in $X_3$ for example is, as you say, $\frac{m_3}{n}$.  Similiarly, the probability of selecting a point in both $X_3$ and $X_7$ would be $\frac{l_{37}}{n}$.

It is certainly possible that the intersection of all $10$ sets is empty, in which case the probability of selecting a point lying in all $10$ of the sets would be $0$.  However, assuming the intersection of all 10 sets is nonempty, the probability of selecting a point in the intersection of all $10$ sets is $\frac{|X_1 \cap X_2 \cap ... \cap X_{10}|}{n}$.  (However, it is not clear to me we have enough information to determine the size of this intersection.)

Comment: Reason I think there might not be enough information to determine the size of the intersection of all $10$ sets: Suppose that instead of $10$ we only had $3$ subsets and suppose $l_{ij}=1$ for all $i \neq j$.  If all $3$ sets intersect at the same point, $|X_1 \cap X_2 \cap X_3| = 1$.  However, if each set intersects the two other sets at different points we still have $l_{ij}=1$ for all $i \neq j$, but in this case $|X_1 \cap X_2 \cap X_3| = 0$.

Comment: Yes I agree.. but to estimate the cardinality of the intersection of 3,4,... sets, can I do the following:  let's say we have $|A|$, $|B|$, $|C|$, $|A\cap B|$, $|A\cap C|$ and $|B\cap C|$ given. I want to calculate $|A\cap B\cap C|$. I want to use: $|A\cap B\cap C|=|(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap C)|$ and the estimation calculation from question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583470/expected-value-of-probability-of-intersection
$E(|(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap C)|:|A\cap B|=m_1, |A\cap C|=m_2) = \frac{m_1*m_2}{a}$ since we look for all elements in $A$ (not $U$ to be more precise)

Comment: if they lie in the intersections. We do the same for $(A\cap B)\cap(B\cap C)$ and so on. Then we calculate the middle. Would that make sense?